# Metro dialog not working

Tags: c#, wpf, mahapps.metro

I've been using metro controls in my wpf application and found that I can use its custom dialog. I've been searching a lot for its implementation, but I can't make it to work. Here's how I use it.

```
Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() =>
{
    this.ShowCustomDialog("Select task before", "Message");
}));

public async Task<MessageDialogResult> ShowCustomDialog(string message, string title)
{
    return await this.ShowMessageAsync(title, message);
}
```

Note: I'm using a dispatcher because I'm executing this code inside a KeyListener which is on a different thread from the UI thread.

Here's the display result:

[image]

I think there's something's missing or I'm kind of the right track because the window blackens meaning the code got executed, but the message is not there.

Most of the implementation I saw was applications running on full screen and mine's has a fixed width and height. Maybe it doesn't support applications not running on full screen? Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: What is "metro controls"? is that some kind of UI library for WPF?

Comment: Yes. FYR http://mahapps.com/

Comment: I'm a bit puzzled by the use of async in displaying a message to the user and calling that from a Dispatcher invocation.. Why is it like that?

Comment: I just based my implementations with the documents provided on their site. Regarding the dispatcher, I specified in my post why I'm using it.

Comment: But you are creating a new background thread from within the dispatcher call. So its redundant.

Comment: Can you supply a more specific answer on what I am doing wrong? I'm not that fully knowledgeable about threading.

Comment: I don't think threading is the cause of your problem, just seems bizarre.